# where "not null" clause in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I want to retrieve notes from database where notes are (not null), I wrote the following code:

```
public Cursor getmynotesss(int id){
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, NOTES_TABLE, new String[] {
            NOTE_TEXT, PAGE_NO,BOOK_ID},BOOK_ID + "=? AND "+NOTE_TEXT+" IS NOT NULL OR "+NOTE_TEXT+" != ''" ,
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

but it still gives me the null notes. 
what is the wrong in my code?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the `OR` condition should be `AND` :

```
"=? AND "+NOTE_TEXT+" IS NOT NULL AND "+NOTE_TEXT+" != ''"
```

Comment: What is the value of NOTE_TEXT ?

Comment: public final static String NOTE_TEXT="note_txt"; it is the name of text field

Answer (score 2):

i have solve my problem like this

```
SELECT pk_video_master_id AS _id,
video_title,
video_added_date,
video_thumbnail FROM tbl_video_master
WHERE NOT video_detail_last_view ='' // this is return not null values and work for me 
ORDER BY video_detail_last_view ASC";
```

so you can try like this

```
Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, NOTES_TABLE,new String[] {NOTE_TEXT,AGE_NO,BOOK_ID},BOOK_ID + "=? AND NOT "+NOTE_TEXT+" = ''" ,new String[] {String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
      Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, NOTES_TABLE, new String[] {
        NOTE_TEXT, PAGE_NO,BOOK_ID}, NOTE_TEXT+" IS NOT NULL AND "+BOOK_ID + "=?" ,
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

and not equals in SQLITE is "<>" not "!="

Comment: are you sure they are nulls -- some space ?

Comment: in case of space it will come up as space is not null try adding AND "+NOTE_TEXT+" <> ''"

Comment: instead of != add <> as "!= " is not valid in sqlite

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
IS NOT NULL
```

with

```
<>``
```